# Bash Commands from vim

Tags: linux, vim, path, terminal

When I run bash commands from inside of vim I notice that the path is all wrong. Is there a way inside of my .vimrc to have it load my .bash_profile or just inherit the PATH and alias settings from the terminal it's launched from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you define the shell as interactive, vim will load your .bashrc or .bash_profile. Default it is not loaded.

This can be done by:

```
:set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

default is only `-c`, `:h shellcmdflag` to see detail. of course you could add it in your .vimrc file.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly the answer I was looking for. You deserve a metal.

Comment: The problem of this command on Fedora is vim is suspending on file save.

Answer (score 2):

If you've properly done `export PATH` in your profile, Vim should inherit the shell's `PATH` setting. You can check via `:echo $PATH` from inside Vim, and also manipulate it via `:let $PATH .= ':/additional/path'`.

If you also need aliases, you have to use Kent's solution. A word of caution: With this modification of `'shellcmdflag'`, you may (depending on the complexity of your shell environment) incur a runtime penalty for *every* shell invocation from Vim.

Comment: You *will* incur a runtime penalty for every shell invocation (including `system()` invokation), even without any configuration files (bash will have to first check whether they are present). You only *may* incur *notable* runtime penalty.